# CSS menu hovering not working for all items

Tags: html, css, hover

The example below should have in the CSS main-nav with hover so the items get a block around the menu items when pointed with the mouse. Somehow this only works with ABOUT at the right, but not the other menu items in the main-nav. Is there something missing? Could this be a child parent issue?

**HTML** index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo1.png">
    </div>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> DOCUMENTS </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> LOGIN </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="hero">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Watch Video </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More </a>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** style.css

```
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.05),rgba(0,0,0,0.05)),url(pic1.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.main-nav
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a
{
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover
{
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img
{
    width: 115px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

body
{
    font-family: monospace;
}

.row
{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.hero
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h1
{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 275px;
}

.button
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 440px;
}

.btn
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-one
{
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-one:hover
{
    background-color: seagreen;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.btn-two
{
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

    .btn-two:hover
{
    background-color: darkorange;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that your `.hero` element has absolute position and is positioned at the top left (due to the applying default settings), so it overlaps most of the other code. You should change that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. In your code, we have added class "**navbar**" along with "**row**" and given position relative and z-index to achieve the desired requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/f96mrp5x/2/

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)), url(pic1.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  width: 115px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 275px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 440px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-one {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-one:hover {
  background-color: seagreen;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.btn-two {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="row navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo1.png">
        </div>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> DOCUMENTS </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> LOGIN </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hero">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div class="button">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Watch Video </a>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```